# Why does the * selector not work in css?

Tags: css

I am implementing some code, and keep on getting an error whenever I attempt to use the `*`. Here is the code

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

and here is the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'
```

Edit: Here is the part where the css is being added into the html

> <script src="slideshow.css"> </script>

Comment: it does not throw any error for me can you show more or all your css file and js code

Comment: In all probability that's **not** in CSS; that error seems to be coming from JavaScript.

Comment: can you share you latest code because this is not css error this is javascript error.

Comment: I never know that css can throw error message like javascript. Wierd!

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill check

Comment: It does show css:line1

Comment: The full part is as follows * {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

Comment: can you add the part of your HTML where you import your css to your question please

Comment: CSS is included in HTML with the link tag in the head element. You seem to use the script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to import a css stylesheet you need to use a `link` tag :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">`

Documentation of <link> : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

The link element is used to load external resources which are not executable : css, icons or fonts

`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`

`<link rel="preload" href="myFont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">`

---

While

> The HTML <script> element is used to embed or reference executable code; this is typically used to embed or refer to JavaScript code. The  element can also be used with other languages, such as WebGL's GLSL shader programming language.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind next time I do something like this